# How to make separate tabs have different information inside of them in python tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, tabs

I'm trying to make a text editor app with python Tkinter and tabs with the notebook function. I have 1 problem, when I add the input text box to the screen it works perfectly I tried writing with it and yes it worked, but when I switched to another tab the same text is there and I tried multiple solutions like functions that make another input and if statements, I also saw a StackOverflow post that showed how to use if statements (I **don't** have the link) but it still didn't work for me.

here is my code :

```
nb = ttk.Notebook(window)

tab1 = ttk.Frame(nb)
tab2 = ttk.Frame(nb)
  
nb.add(tab1, text ='Tab 1')
nb.add(tab2, text ='Tab 2')
nb.pack(expand = 1, fill ="both")
  
ttk.Label(tab1)
ttk.Label(tab2)

editor_text_box = Text(
        window,
        height=12,
        width=40
)     
editor_text_box.pack()
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not putting the text widget in a frame, you're putting it in the parent of the notebook.

If you want a widget to appear in a tab, it must be a child of the frame for that tab.

```
editor_text_box = Text(tab1, ...)
```

Comment: when i did that it only gave me an error

Comment: @Nneka: without knowing the error I can't help. If you want something to appear in a notebook tab, it must be a child of that notebook tab or one of its children. That's just how tabs work. You can't put a widget outside a widget and expect it to appear inside. When I take your code, add enough to make it runnable, and follow the advice in this answer, the text widget appears inside the first tab.